# Crontab to stop and restart a server

Tags: cron

I have a node.js server running in my linux VPS. Currently I go to the server's directory and type `node server.js`. After 1 hour I must stop it and restart. So what I'm doing is resume the server screen and using ctrl+C then running `node server.js` again. How can I do this using crontab?

My server path:

```
/var/www/server/server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding on this you can install [Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-service) with NodeJs App.

```
npm install -g forever 

forever start path/to/file/server.js

forever list 

forever stop path/to/file/serverstopstart.sh or app name
```

To see more help

```
forever-service install --help
```

To use it with Cronjob:

```
touch serverstopstart.sh
```

Edit *vi serverstopstart.sh* and paste below entry:

```
forever stop path/to/file/server.js

forever start path/to/file/server.js
```

Save file

Open Crontab:

```
crontab -e 

* */1 * * *  path/to/file/serverstopstart.sh
```

Save File

Give permission to file to execute it.

```
chmod +x path/to/file/serverstopstart.sh
```

Comment: `* */1 * * *  path/to/file/serverstopstart.sh` will do the job 24/7, right?

Comment: As you mentioned it required to execute for every 1 hours you can schedule as per your need. (“At every minute of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 and 23rd hour.” ), it will work 24/7.

Comment: Alright, that's exactly what I need. Thank You very much. I'm only concerned about the stop part, it seems something is wrong in my forever. Cause it shows a lot of info and I can't make sure it really stopped the server...

http://prntscr.com/9yvuus

Here's a screeshot of it.

Comment: Try to execute _forever start server.js then _forever list_ and share its output here.

Comment: It's showing the same tons of info

Comment: It looks OK you can check your nodejs app if its working or not  ?

Comment: It is working, now i got `forever list` to work. The output: info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command             script                    forever pid   id logfile                 uptime
data:    [0] eimh /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/server/server.js 30024   30029    /root/.forever/eimh.log 0:0:0:22.754

Comment: But I can't be sure it is stopping the process before running it again, I'm afraid it is running the server multiple times. How can I be sure?

Comment: You can can schedule the cron every 1 or 5 minute to verify it. once verified you can revert cron for every 1 hour.

Comment: How to verify? Sorry I'm really not used to linux.

Comment: You can try to stop/start by executing _sh serverstopstart.sh_ script first and check if your nodejs server performing as you needed.

Comment: I just found out, it's not stopping the server.js, only running a new one. So the file's first line is not working

Comment: You can use an uid to start _forever --uid "myapp" start server.js_  to stop it  _forever --uid "myapp" stop server.js_

Comment: this is not working. error:   Cannot start forever
error:   log file /root/.forever/server.log exists. Use the -a or --append option to append log.

Comment: Sorry little mistake here : give try with  an uid to start _forever --uid "myapp" start server.js_  to stop it _forever stop myapp_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35287/discussion-between-marciel-fonseca-and-ramesh-chand).